# ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
CASE
    tbl_appointment_types."name" 
    WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" LIKE 'Refill-ART' THEN
    'Re-Fill' 
    WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" = 'Enhanced Adherence'::character varying THEN
    'Enhanced Adherence' 
    WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" = 'PHARMACY APPOINTMENT'::character varying THEN
    'Re-Fill' ELSE tbl_appointment_types."name" 
END 
FROM
    tbl_appointment INNER JOIN tbl_appointment_types ON tbl_appointment_types."id" = tbl_appointment.app_type_1 
GROUP BY
    tbl_appointment_types."name";
```

When I try running it, I get the  following error:

```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = boolean
  LINE 4:  WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" LIKE 'Refill-ART' THEN
           ^
  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

> Time: 0.054s
```

How can I solve the following issue?

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: The `group by` seems pretty useless as you don't use any aggregates

Answer (score 5):

The CASE expression comes in two flavors:

A "short" form that only supports equality where you first state the expression and then the values to which that should be compared (using `=`), e.g.

```
 CASE some_column
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Two'
    ELSE 'Something else'
 END
```

Or a more verbose version where you can use different condition for each `WHEN`. But in that case you can **not** have the expression after the CASE:

```
 CASE -- nothing here!
    WHEN some_column = 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN some_column = 2 THEN 'Two'
    ELSE 'Something else'
 END
```

So you need to write your CASE expression as:

```
CASE -- nothing here!
   WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" LIKE 'Refill-ART' THEN 'Re-Fill' 
   WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" = 'Enhanced Adherence' THEN 'Enhanced Adherence' 
   WHEN tbl_appointment_types."name" = 'PHARMACY APPOINTMENT' THEN 'Re-Fill' 
   ELSE tbl_appointment_types."name" 
END
```

---

Using LIKE without a wildcard doesn't really makes sense. `"name" LIKE 'Refill-ART'` is the same as `"name" = 'Refill-ART'`.

You probably meant `"name" LIKE 'Refill-ART%'` (note the `%` at the end)